# ECSlidingViewController on detail view only

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have an app that displays a UICollectionView with navigation controller and then taping an item brings you to the detail view of that item. I want to add the ECSlidingViewController to ONLY the detail view to have additional information underneath the the detail view.

The best class I have found so far is ECSlidingViewController which can be found here: [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController)

Looking through the example, I am unable to find out to create this effect in ONLY the detail view and not the whole app.

I have been trying to figure this out for days and cant seem to get it to work correctly. I have followed all the steps but applied then to the detail view and it will not work.

My project is using storyboards.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: A sliding view change isn't that hard to implement on your own. Do you need the dragging feature of ECSlidingViewController, or do you just want the new controller to slide in and out on a button click?

Comment: I am looking to have the slide and button feature together.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question -- it looks like in the ECSlidingViewController demo, you can slowly drag the view across if you want to, as opposed to when you press a button, it slides in at a predetermined speed, just like a push animation. So my question is whether you need this drag behavior in addition to the slide.